# Using instantiated class members as variables in abstract class methods

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, abstract

I'm trying to figure out how to make a method in a base abstract class capable of using member values of instantiated objects derived from the class.  For example, let's say I have a class called `Vehicle` that inherits an interface called `IVehicle`;

```
public abstract class Vehicle : IVehicle
{
    public int Wheels = 4;

    public int CountWheels()
    {
        return Wheels;
    }
}
```

Let's say I then had another class called `Motorcycle` that inherited `Vehicle` as such;

```
public class Motorcycle : Vehicle, IVehicle
{
    public int Wheels = 2;
}
```

If I make a new `Motorcycle` called `newMotorcycle` and I call `newMotorcycle.CountWheels()`, I get 4 instead of 2.  I'm assuming this is an issue with my `Wheels` definition in the `Motorcycle` class, but I've tried just about everything I can think of to get this to work and it always seems to want to ignore child class definitions.  I know that I could make the `CountWheels()` method abstract and define it in the `Motorcycle` class, but I'm trying to keep the base `Vehicle` class as generic as possible so I can implement a ton of other child classes without having to redefine the same method over and over.

My first question; is what I'm trying to do even possible?  If so, what part of my member definition needs to change for this to work the way I'm intending for it to?

I promise I scoured the internet before I posted this here and I couldn't find enough information to help myself...

Comment: Why do you need wheels and countWheels? You could e.g. return 4 in Vehicle.countWheels as a default value, then override Motorcycle.countWheels and return 2. And remove wheels. Just an example...

Comment: @ElDuderino One could surmise this is an MCVE and that his real code is less contrived

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will notice that there is a warning in the code you posted:

> Motorcycle.Wheels hides inherited member Vehicle.Wheels...

Hence your problem, `Vehicle` has no idea that a derived class has *hidden* one of its members (hence why hiding is a bad idea).

Since you can't have virtual fields, you should change it to a virtual (or in this case, abstract so everyone has to define it) *property*:

```
public abstract class Vehicle : IVehicle
{
    public abstract int Wheels {get;}

    public int CountWheels()
    {
        return Wheels;
    }
}

public class Motorcycle : Vehicle, IVehicle
{
    public int Wheels => 2;
}
```

Now every derived class will have to have a `Wheels` property that the base class can use.

Comment: I appreciate it.  I noticed the warning and tried to rectify it but went about it the wrong way.  I appreciate the speedy response!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `Wheels` member `virtual` and `override` it, otherwise you're just "hiding" the base member. You'll also need to change it to a property in order to make it `virtual`:

```
public abstract class Vehicle 
{
    public virtual int Wheels { get { return 4; } }

    public int CountWheels()
    {
        return Wheels;
    }
}

public class Motorcycle : Vehicle
{
    public override int Wheels { get { return 2; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up `virtual` properties and methods (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

You need `Wheels` to be `public virtual int Wheels {get; set;}` in base and `public override int Wheels {get; set;}` in derived

Then you can initialize the value as you need in each class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option. Rather than defining `Wheels` as a virtual property on `Vehicle`, and overriding that property on `Motorcycle`, you can define `Wheels` as an ordinary property and then set it in the constructor for `Motorcycle`:

```
public abstract class Vehicle : IVehicle
{
    public int Wheels { get; protected set; }

    public Vehicle()
    {
        Wheels = 4;
    }

    public int CountWheels()
    {
        return Wheels;
    }
}

public class Motorcycle : Vehicle, IVehicle
{
    public Motorcycle()
    {
        Wheels = 2;
    }
}
```